# ACF InnerBlocks breaks css grid, How can we add classes to allowedblocks (Wordpress Gutenberg)

Tags: block-editor

When I create an ACF Innerblock with allowedblocks, childs blocks are wrapped inside a wp-block div that breaks my grid system.

For example a simple grid system like that :

```
<div class="grid-wrapper innerblock">
  <div class="grid-item allowedblock col3 "></div>
  <div class="grid-item allowedblock col3 "></div>
  <div class="grid-item allowedblock col3 "></div>
  <div class="grid-item allowedblock col3 "></div>
</div>
```

Will output this breaking code in the admin :

```
<div class="grid-wrapper block-editor-block-list__layout" data-is-drop-zone="true">

  <div class="wp-block"> <!-- no class "col3" !! -->  
      <div class="grid-item allowedblock col3 "></div>
  </div>

  <div class="wp-block"> <!-- no class "col3" !! --> 
      <div class="grid-item allowedblock col3 "></div>
  </div>

  <div class="wp-block"> <!-- no class "col3" !! -->
      <div class="grid-item allowedblock col3 "></div>
  </div>

  <div class="wp-block"> <!-- no class "col3" !! -->
      <div class="grid-item allowedblock col3 "></div>
  </div>


</div>
```

What's the solution to pass the class "col3" to the dynamics wp-blocks ?
I tried it, but it didn't work...

```
<div class="block-wrapper">

  <?php 
     $template = array( 
    array( "acf/card", array( "className" => "col3" ) ) 
     );

  ?>
    
  <InnerBlocks 
    class=" grid-wrapper" 
    allowedBlocks="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_json_encode( array( 'acf/card') ) ); ?> "
    template="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_json_encode( $template ) ); ?>"
  />

</div>
```

Comment: ACF using `<InnerBlocks />` in PHP is functionality specific to that plugin, and is not how Inner Blocks works when creating blocks with React using the WordPress APIs, so this is probably something you're going to need to contact the developer about, as third party plugins are off topic here.

Comment: @Jacob Peattie Hello, sorry, I though that we could ask about pluggin problems too. I have the same problem using the natives functions with React too, so I'm changing this question with the react version. Is it okay like that ?